# Download/import all dependencies from Spring IO

Tags: spring, maven

I work for a large organization where all development tools must go through a rigorous certification process and security assessment. I want to have Spring IO Brussels SR2 certified, along with Apache Maven.

I'd like to provide them with a ZIP file containing all JARs (dependencies and transitive dependencies) of the Spring IO platform so they can do the security assessment on it.

Being a new Maven user, I've created a new Maven project in Eclipse, and simple added this in pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySpringApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MySpringApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Brussels-SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MySpringApp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

The project compiles and packages correctly, but it's not importing/adding any JARs to the packaged WAR file. I've also tried to change the scope to compile.

Is it possible? Is it because it's a bill of material?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Website](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) you have to enable the dependency-tree using

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySpringApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MySpringApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>Brussels-SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <build>
        <finalName>MySpringApp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Eclipse and Maven are designed to be able to work alone, a bit of experiences is required to let them work together, often a cleanup using <kbd>Update Project ...</kbd> (project-rightclick/maven) is required

Comment: Do you mean entering all possible modules by hand?

Comment: @CharlesMorin No, just add this single dependency, the `<dependencyManagement>` you already added will `import` all the rest.

Comment: When adding the spring-core dependency, Eclipse complains about providing a version number, which I don't want. That's why I'm using Spring IO... Any thoughts?

Comment: @CharlesMorin Eclipse and Maven are designed to be able to work alone, a bit of experiences is required to let them work together, often a cleanup using `Update Project ...` (project-rightclick/maven) is required..

Comment: Now the project builds and packages properly, but the only JAR I get in /WEB-INF/lib is spring-core-4.3.8.jar. I would like to have all those JARs from https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading the dependency versions list into a CSV file, then loop through it in a simple Java class, outputting the results in a  tag manually. Then, I was able to copy/paste all those  tags into my pom.xml file and then get all those dependencies resolved by Maven.

Finally, I have taken the content of /target/WEB-INF/lib.